# Entity Framework returning bad data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework 6.1 project that is querying a SQL Server 2012 database table and getting back incorrect results.

To illustrate what is happening, I created 2 queries that should have the exact same results. The table `ProjectTable` has 23 columns and 20500ish rows:

```
var test1 = db.ProjectTable
    .GroupBy(t => t.ProjectOwner)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToArray();

var test2 = db.ProjectTable
    .ToArray()
    .GroupBy(t => t.ProjectOwner)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

The queries are designed to get a list of all of the distinct project owners in the table. The first query does the heavy lifting on the SQL Server, where as the second query downloads the entire table into memory and then processes it on the client side.

The first variable `test1` has a length of about 300 items. The second variable `test2` has a length of 5.

Here are the raw SQL queries that EF is generating:

```
-- test1
SELECT [Distinct1].[ProjectOwner] AS [ProjectOwner]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT
       [Extent1].[ProjectOwner] AS [ProjectOwner]
       FROM [dbo].[ProjectTable] as [Extent1]
     ) AS [Distinct1]

-- test2
SELECT Col1, Col2 ... ProjectOwner, ... Col23
FROM [dbo].[ProjectTable]
```

When I run this query and analyze the returned entities, I notice that the full 20500ish rows are returned, but the `ProjectOwner` column gets overridden with one of only 5 different users!

```
var test = db.ProjectTable.ToArray();
```

I thought that maybe it was the SQL Server, so I did a packet trace and filtered on TDS. Randomly looking through the raw streams I see many names that aren't in the list of 5, so I know that data is being sent across the wire correctly.

How do I see the raw data that EF is getting? Is there something that might be messing with the cache and pulling incorrect results?

If I run the queries in either SSMS or Visual Studio, the list returned is correctly. It is only EF that has this issue.

### EDIT

Ok, I added another test to make sure my sanity is in check.
I took the `test2` raw sql query and did the following:

```
var test3 = db.Database
    .SqlQuery<ProjectTable>(@"SELECT Col1..Col23")
    .ToArray()
    .Select(t => t.ProjectOwner)
    .Distict()
    .ToArray();
```

and I get the correct 300ish names back!

### So, in short:

1. Having EF send projected DISTINCT query to SQL Server returns the correct results
2. Having EF select the entire table and then using LINQ to project and DISTINCT the data returns incorrect results
3. Giving EF **THE EXACT SAME QUERY!!!** that bullet #2 generates and doing a raw SQL query, returns the correct results

Comment: You can, in debug mode stop the query before it's sent to see what EF is doing.  EF generates SQL to send to the server, and it's my guess the code is sufficiently different to generate different SQL.  Understanding how EF is part of the equation when using only LINQ.  If you don't like the results you can always send the query directly to SQL layer using EF.Database.Query<ofType>()  where the results are put into the model you pass in.

Comment: _"How do I see the raw data that EF is getting?"_ - by profiling, either SQL of Entity Framework.

Comment: I have both SQL queries, and yes, they are very different.  I'll update the question with the actual queries.  As for profiling, I've profiled and packet traced from the SQL side, and the data is correctly streaming across.  How so I profile what EF is doing with the raw data?

Comment: Are you selecting from a **view** on SQL Server by any chance?

Comment: Not an answer, but still: `db.ProjectTable.Select(t => t.ProjectOwner).Distinct()` better expresses your intent, and may yield a better query.

Comment: @marc_s - It is a table

Comment: What is the data type of `ProjectOwner` -- and, if it's a character type, its collation? SQL Server's `DISTINCT` does not use the same equality comparison logic as C#.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - The original query in question needs the groupings (the query that was giving me the weird results), so I started the whole thing by debugging that one query. Changing the test over to `.Select(t => t.ProjectOwner).Distinct()` still gives me incorrect results

Comment: Just to be clear here -- are you saying `db.ProjectTable.ToArray()` returns a table that is different from what you get if you do `SELECT * FROM ProjectTable`? If so, take a hard look at where `ProjectTable` is coming from and if your `DbSet` is doing anything funny.

Comment: The second query is actually just LINQ, if projectowner is a string, then the processing on SQL in group by is different than in LINQ because LINQ is going to be case sensitive whereas SQL is not.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: that was my first thought as well, but that should mean the first query returns *less* items than the second, not *more*. Unless the OP swapped them by accident.

Comment: well, you should try using https://entityframework.codeplex.com/ to try understand the behavior.... thanks in advance :)

Comment: btw, this is not the axact same code : `db.Database.SqlQuery<ProjectTable>(@"SELECT Col1..Col23").ToArray().GroupBy(t => t.ProjectOwner).Select(g => g.Key)  .ToArray();` would be the same code.

Comment: @tschmit007 - Yes, it would be. I converted everything in my project over to the `.Select().Distinct()` syntax.  It is the same then, and replacing the query with the other format produces the exact same results for all 3 tests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After downloading the Entity Framework source and stepping through many an `Enumerator`, I found the issue.

In the `Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly`method ([found here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Common/internal/materialization/shaper.cs)), on line 187 the `Context.ObjectStateManager.FindEntityEntry` method is called.  To my surprise, a non-null value was returned!  Wait a minute, there shouldn't be any cached results, since I'm returning all rows?!

That's when I discovered that my Table has no Primary Key!

*In my defence, the table is actually a cache of a view that I'm working with, I just did a* `SELECT * INTO CACHETABLE FROM USERVIEW`

I then looked at which column Entity Framework *thought* was my Primary Key (they call it a singleton key) and it just so happens that the column they picked had only... *drum roll please*... **5 unique values!**

When I looked at the model that EF generated, sure enough! That column was specified as a primary key.  I changed the key to the appropriate column and now everything is working as it should!