# EntityFramework returns corrupted/swaped data from SQL Server View

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, lambda, decimal

I have simple query from a view in SQL Server:

```
SELECT [PricePerM]
FROM RealtyStatParent
ORDER BY PricePerM
```

When I execute the query in SQL Management Studio I get correct results. It means I get 2532 rows starting from 1.00 and ending by 173543.6893.

When I make a query from C# using entity framework, I got the same results:

```
var justDecimals = context.RealtyStatParents                
    .OrderBy(item => item.PricePerM)
    .Select(item => item.PricePerM)
    .ToArray();
```

Until now nothing special. But what I really don't understand is following query. I select entire rows first and then I select the price (decimal).

```
var entireRows = context.RealtyStatParents                
    .OrderBy(item => item.PricePerM)        
    .ToArray();

var decimalFromRows = entireRows 
    .Select(item => item.PricePerM)
    .ToArray();
```

A lot of values of PricePerM are repeated (value 1 or 48) instead of a real value and the resultset is not ordered properly.

The definition of row in EF designer is simple:

```
public partial class RealtyStatParent
{
    public Nullable<decimal> PricePerM { get; set; }
    public int BusinessCategory { get; set; }
    public decimal obec_kod { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I Believe that this strange behavior has something to do with [Entity Framework returning bad data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701307/entity-framework-returning-bad-data), because the view has no primary key. EF decided that Entity Key is on Column BusinessCategory and obec_kod, which is combined unique. I hope I am closer, but still not enough.

Comment: Just to make sure the debugger is not trolling you, have you tried tracing or emitting the values to the console?

Comment: Yes, the prices are wrong. I see it in HTML on website.

Comment: This is really weird.  I hope someone shows up who has a solution.  This question has only been viewed 16 times so far, which is kind of unfortunate.  I am adding the C# tag, it might help to get it noticed.

Comment: Well, the ordering issue is simple - since you didn't specify an explicit ordering in `decimalFromRows`, you're not going to get any. It doesn't explain the duplicate values, though - it looks like you're having multi-threading issues or something, but that wouldn't happen with simple synchronous code that only works with locals. Are you sure the issue actually reproduce if you just make a simple program with only the code you've shown? Are you sure you don't have e.g. your own `ToArray` method or something like that? What if you do the `Select` part first?

Comment: `decimalsFromRow` is not obviously not in order, so maybe the order get's somehow srewed up. Can you add an order to the second call?

Comment: @Luan: This example is an console application which read prices, clean data from artefacts, make analysis and save averages prices to database. Perfectly reproducible. I debug it on backup of DB as console app on my dev laptop. I didn't modified LINQ nor EF. It is just standard code. There is no multi-threading and anyway I cannot imagine how multi-threading issue can affect local variable.

Comment: @Sasha: The problem is not only ordering, but also data corruption. The prices are replaced by duplication from different rows.

Answer (score 4):

The cause of this strange behavior is already mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701307/entity-framework-returning-bad-data) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227990/entity-framework-query-against-view-in-ef-c-code-returns-duplicate-results). It seems that the EF internally cache the entire table, but EF selected wrong unique key and in consequence the the data in the row get replaced by data from different rows.

This SELECT is made from a view. This view has no primary key. EF decided to be too clever and choose the primary key on his own for caching purposes. But EF has chosen wrong key, I mean EF has chosen only 2 columns of four.

**To fix it, go to the EDMX model, right click to the header of problematic View and choose "Show in model browser". Then check, that all columns has the property EntityKey set to true. That is all.**

Because of this and other "features" of EF I am bit disappointed by EF. This code worked fine in LinqToSQL wihtout any magic. And it is not the first query when LinqToSql behave correctly and EF behavior is at least problematic or crashing runtime. I am afraid Microsoft is breaking "get what you expect pattern" here. When I query the entire view, I just expect simple code which get the data from the view.

[image]